# How can i find all ydl_opts

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl

```
ydl_opts = {
    'verbose': True,                       #like this
    'format': '{}'.format(int(comboget)),  #format,vebrose,ottmpl
    'outtmpl': '%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s', #how can i find
    'noplaylist': mt,                      #all dictionary
    'logger': MyLogger(),                  #options
    'progress_hooks': [durum],             #how can i find
}
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)
ydl.download([url])
```

how can i find all ydl_opts in here https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All options for the Python Module are listed in [YoutubeDL.py](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L128-L278)

Here is a small excerpt

> ```
> username:          Username for authentication purposes.
> password:          Password for authentication purposes.
> videopassword:     Password for accessing a video.
> usenetrc:          Use netrc for authentication instead.
> verbose:           Print additional info to stdout.
> quiet:             Do not print messages to stdout.
> no_warnings:       Do not print out anything for warnings.
> forceurl:          Force printing final URL.
> forcetitle:        Force printing title.
> forceid:           Force printing ID.
> forcethumbnail:    Force printing thumbnail URL.
> forcedescription:  Force printing description.
> forcefilename:     Force printing final filename.
> forceduration:     Force printing duration.
> forcejson:         Force printing info_dict as JSON.
> dump_single_json:  Force printing the info_dict of the whole playlist
>                    (or video) as a single JSON line.
> ...
> ```